# How to access PHP environment variables in a bash script?

Tags: php, linux, bash, unix

I'm writing a bash script meant to run on a remote AMP stack. The script needs to access a PHP predefined environment variable ($_ENV).

This is what I want:

```
db_host=$(php -r 'echo $_ENV{DATABASE_SERVER};')
echo "The DB Host is: $db_host"
# output: "The DB Host is: internal-db.s173785.gridserver.com"
```

This is what I get instead:

```
# METHOD 1
db_host1=$(php -r 'echo $_ENV{DATABASE_SERVER};')
echo "The DB Host is: $db_host1"
# output: "The DB Host is: "

# METHOD 2
db_host2=`php -r 'echo get_env(DATABASE_SERVER);'`
echo "The DB Host is: $db_host2"
# output: "The DB Host is: "
```

Neither method works, both variables return empty. I know that this PHP variable is set, because when I type this into the terminal (after ssh'ing into the server), I get the expected value:

```
$ php -r 'echo $_ENV{DATABASE_SERVER};' 
# outputs: "internal-db.s173785.gridserver.com"
```

Technically the above methods should work, because I managed to get this working in my script:

```
php_user=$(php -r 'echo getenv("USER");')
echo php_user is $php_user
# outputs: "php_user is myusername"
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?\

*****UPDATE*********

I should mention that I am invoking this script from my local machine like so:

```
ssh -t user@mydomain.com "myscript backup_remote_db"
```

"myscript" is the name of my executable bash script, and "backup_remote_db" is the function I'm passing to it which contains the code above.

This might not be cause however, because when I echo $USER in the script, it echoes the remote user, not the local one...

*****UPDATE 2********

Here is how I finally got it working:

```
db_host=$DATABASE_SERVER
echo "The DB Host is $db_host"
# output: "The DB Host is: internal-db.s173785.gridserver.com"
```

But only if I make this adjustment to how the script is invoked:

```
ssh -t user@mydomain.com ". /etc/profile; myscript backup_remote_db"
```

Comment: What prints `echo $DATABASE_SERVER` ?

Comment: I get internal-db.s173785.gridserver.com!! brilliant

Comment: You don't need php for get environment variables in your shell

Comment: I can echo $DATABASE_SERVER from the command line, and that works fine. But when I do that from the bash script it comes up blank. There might be a reason for that, and I've added those details to my original question.

Comment: Are you sure, that script runs with same environment? may be it runs from other user or something like this?

Comment: Where is `DATABASE_SERVER` set in the first place? Your `.bashrc` perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure where `DATABASE_SERVER` is set, but there is no .bashrc or .bash_profile or anything like that. @vp_arth I'm not sure how to check that, `echo $USER` works as expected in the script. echo $DATABASE_SERVER works from the command line, but not the script.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps `/etc/profile` then? It must be somewhere :)

Comment: ok, it's here: /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: So then you need to have `. /etc/bash.bashrc` in your script and then you can use `$DATABASE_SERVER`.

Comment: thanks @Jack, i will check with MediaTemple, the hosting company, to see exactly where it is DATABASE_SERVER is set. But I think you guys are right, ssh needs to source some configuration file first.

Comment: @Jack oh, you had the answer all along with your suggestion to use /etc/profile. My mistake, points for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need php for get environment variables in your shell

Just print it:

```
 echo "The DB Host is $DATABASE_SERVER"
```

And for full answer, I assume, that php doesn't work because you get notice `Use of undefined constant PATH`, you should wrap your string arguments.
This should work:

```
v=$(php -r 'print_r(getenv("DATABASE_SERVER"));')
echo "DB: $v"
```

**Update:**
.bashrc is not sourced when you log in using SSH. You need to source it in your .bash_profile like this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: When using single quotes in `bash`'s `echo`, the `$v` doesn't get interpreted (it prints `DB: $v`) whereas with double quotes it prints the expected output.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for me, `v` still comes up blank

Comment: `cat ~/.bashrc` gives: No such file or directory. I can't find the .bashrc

Comment: simple change it to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: i looked in /etc/bash.bashrc and DATABASE_SERVER is not set in there either, so sourcing it doesn't work. I'm going to investigate some more regarding where it's set. I'll be back, thanks so much you guys for your help.

Comment: @vp_arth yep, this is the answer. I finally found the dotfile I needed, it was /etc/profile. I update my bash script to include `. /etc/profile` before running the script, and now it works. So you taught me two thing: first, environment variables exist independent of PHP. Second, there's a difference between executing a command via ssh, versus when ssh'ing into a server via command line. In the latter case, it sources all kinds of dot files behind the scenes. Thanks everyone.